# Can't find xml file that I've created on my device

Tags: android, xml, delphi, delphi-xe6

I've just starting to playing with Android and Delphi. I have quite strange problem because I can not find an xml file on my device that I've created with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LFileName: String;
begin
  LFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'FilesInfo.xml');
  //LFile name resolves to: /data/data/com.embarcadero.XLocator/files/FilesInfo.xml
  if not FileExists(LFileName) then
  begin
    xmlFilesInfo.Active := True;
    xmlFilesInfo.DocumentElement := xmlFilesInfo.CreateNode('Files');
    xmlFilesInfo.SaveToFile(LFileName);
  end else
    xmlFilesInfo.LoadFromFile(LFileName);
end;
```

The file is there somewhere, becasue I see its contents after application start, but I do not know where. The given path does not exist. I've tried to locate this file with Windows Explorer, ES File Explorer and had no success. I do not have an SD card inserted. I've got only two xml files on my entire device and none was the one created by my application.

I do not know if this matters but I've deployed my application in debug mode.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/61728

Comment: Thanks, everything clear now.